# how many cuboids cut from a cube?

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations

A cube has been cut into certain number of cuboids of equal size $2\times3\times4$. What is the least possible integer length of edge of original cube & how many such cuboids are obtained?

My trial:

Assume $a$ is the side of original cube & $n$ is the number of identical cuboids cut from cube then

By volume conservation

$$a^3=n\times 2\times3\times4$$

$a^3=24n\tag 1$
Now i got stuck  because there are two unknowns $a$ & $n$ and only one equation. Please help me solve this problem. thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since you are looking for the *least* length, you should try and minimize $a$ and $n$, so you really don't get an infinite number of solutions.

But also you should think about how a cube can actually be cut up into those cuboids .. maybe some solutions are impossible. That is, you cannot approach this problem *solely* from the standpoint of volume.

HINT

Assuming the cuboids are all aligned the same way, try to find the least common multiple. That should always work (why?)

But maybe by aligning them in different ways, you can make it smaller yet? (if not, why?)

Comment: can you tell me whose LCM is to find however there are two unknowns

Comment: @jeanneclement LCM(2,3,4). Also, can you set $n$ to $1$, $2$, ...?  What is the smallest value of $n$ for which $a$ would be a whole number as well? But again, would that actually translate into a possible scenario in terms of the specific dimensions of the cuboids?

Comment: "But maybe by aligning them in different ways, you can make it smaller yet? (if not, why?)" - I am finding this fiendishly difficult to prove. How do we know the following is true? For a given size of cuboids ($l\times w\times h$), we cannot create a cube smaller than the one with side length $\frac{lcm(l,w,h)^3}{lwh}$.